# SpringBoot, maven and beans in sub-jars

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot

I have couple of maven artefacts:

```
- server (springboot application)
 - api
  - api-impl-01
  - api-impl-02
```

There're two api implementations: api-impl-01 and api-impl-02. In each artefact there are spring beans. The beans from api-impl-01/api-impl-02 are loaded using Condition/@Conditional spring support. The final jar structure is like this:

```
springboot-app.jar
 - BOOT-INF
  - classes
   - server artefact classes
  - lib
   - api.jar
   - api-impl-01.jar
   - api-impl-02.jar
```

The server jar contains api.jar, api-impl-01.jar and api-impl-02.jar in the BOOT-INF/lib directory and classes from server are in BOOT-INF/classes directory.

What is problem here is that the beans from inner jars (api*.jar) are not loaded. Application failed to start with error: Field dbBean in pat.RestEndpoint required a bean of type 'pat.ApiBean' that could not be found.

Please, could someone suggest a solution? I don't want to put all source code into one big maven artefact.

Thanks

'api' artefact:

```
package pat.multidemo.dal.spi;
public interface DalSpi {
    public void print(String msg);
}
```

and

```
package pat.multidemo.dal;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import pat.multidemo.dal.spi.DalSpi;
@Service
public class Dal {
    @Autowired
    private DalSpi dalSpi;
    public void test(String msg) {
        dalSpi.print(msg);
    }
}
```

'impl01' artefact:

```
package pat.multidemo.dal.spi.impl01;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Condition;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionContext;
import org.springframework.core.type.AnnotatedTypeMetadata;
public class Condition01 implements Condition {
    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        return "impl01".equals(System.getProperty("spi.impl"));
    }
}


package pat.multidemo.dal.spi.impl01;
import pat.multidemo.dal.spi.DalSpi;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Conditional;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
@Configuration
public class Config01 {
    @Bean(name = "dal.spi.provider")
    @Conditional(value = Condition01.class)
    public DalSpi dalSpiProvider() {
        return new DalSpi01();
    }
}
```

and

```
package pat.multidemo.dal.spi.impl01;
import pat.multidemo.dal.spi.DalSpi;
public final class DalSpi01 implements DalSpi {
    @Override
    public void print(String msg) {
        System.err.println(this.getClass().getName() + " -> " + msg);
    }
}
```

'impl02' artefact (mostly same as 'impl01'):

```
package pat.multidemo.dal.spi.impl02;
...
public class Condition02 implements Condition {
    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        return "impl02".equals(System.getProperty("spi.impl"));
    }
}


package pat.multidemo.dal.spi.impl02;
...
@Configuration
public class Config02 {
    @Bean(name = "dal.spi.provider")
    @Conditional(value = Condition02.class)
    public DalSpi dalSpiProvider() {
        return new DalSpi02();
    }
}
```

and

```
package pat.multidemo.dal.spi.impl02;
import pat.multidemo.dal.spi.DalSpi;
public final class DalSpi02 implements DalSpi {
    @Override
    public void print(String msg) {
        System.err.println(this.getClass().getName() + " -> " + msg);
    }
}
```

'server' artefact (the application):

```
package pat.multidemo;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
@SpringBootApplication
public class MultiDemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MultiDemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}


package pat.multidemo;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
@Component
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    public JerseyConfig() {
        registerEndpoints();
    }
    private void registerEndpoints() {
        register(Endpoint.class);
    }
}
```

and

```
package pat.multidemo;
import pat.multidemo.dal.Dal;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
@Service
@Path("/test")
public final class Endpoint {
    @Autowired
    private Dal dal;
    @GET
    @Path("/ping")
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String ping(@Context HttpServletRequest servletRequest) {
        dal.test("rest endpoint");
        return "done";
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the package structure of the interfaces and implementations? And how do the annotations on the main class look like?

Comment: You can help the bean factory by adding spring.factories file in the META-INF for each of those modules: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-auto-configuration.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks duffymo. I have to do this:

Add this class to 'api'

```
package pat.multidemo.dal;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
@Configuration
public class DalConfig {
    @Bean(name = "dal.provider")
    public Dal dalProvider() {
        return new Dal();
    }
}
```

Create 'spring.factories' file within META-INF directory in 'api', 'impl01' and 'impl02' projects with line:

- 'api' - *org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=pat.multidemo.dal.DalConfig*
- 'impl01' - *org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=pat.multidemo.dal.spi.impl01.Config01*
- 'impl02' - *org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=pat.multidemo.dal.spi.impl02.Config02*

This works for me.

Thanks